# How to allow the user to select a random number from a 6x6 matrix of unique random numbers in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python. I have to create a 6x6 matrix of unique random numbers with in the range of 1-100. I have created the matrix of random numbers but they are not unique. Moreover, I have to allow the user to select a number from that very specific grid shown on the screen, but I don't know how to do it.

Here is my code

```
# creating a matrix of 6 x 6 but the values of grid should b unique i;e creating a matrix of 36 values   
import random ; 
Random_matrix=[[random.randint(1,100) for row in range(6)] for column in range(6)]
# loops to print the grid
    for i in range(6):
        for j in range(6):
            print(Random_matrix[i][j],end="\t")
        print() 
                  
# allow the user to input a no so that it could b matched with the no selected by the system
    user_no= int(input("hey buddy! guess the number : "))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the user to input the col and row number of the matrix. it can be done with:

`a = [int(x) for x in input("Enter Column and then Row with a space: ").split()]`

this you just need to place the values as

`Random_matrix[a[0]][a[1]]`

I hope this helps

Comment: bro! this was not it.... actually i just wanted to generate a matrix of 6 coloms and 6 rows ...which will have 36 random values...and values should b unique....and then i have to show that matrix on the screen